# Angular JS : Custom directive Issue (directive not working properly if there is a delay of data reception from the api)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Below is a custom directive I have written to format a numeric value into currency with appropriate punctuations and to round the decimal values.

```
var directiveapps = angular.module('myApp.roundedValue', []);
  directiveapps.directive('roundedValue', function () {
   return{
    scope: {
      data: '=items'
    },
    template: '<div>$ {{value|number}}</div>',
    link: function(scope){
      scope.value = Math.round(scope.data* 100) / 100;
    }
  };
});
```

The directive call is as follows,

```
<div class="overallsummary_meter_txt left">
Total Price<br>
<span rounded-value items="totalPrice" class="orange_txt"></span>
</div>
```

The problem I am facing is that I am getting a `null` value if it takes more time to get the numeric value from API.

How can I hold the directive from executing until we get a value from the api to the variable ***item***

I have tried using `scope.$watch` and timeout service, but the results were not satisfactory.

How can I fix this issue ??

Comment: What's wrong with just `<span class="orange_txt">{{totalPrice | number:2}}</span>` ?

Answer (score 0):

try adding ng-if={api data arrives} statement to a directive, so angular will attach the custom directive template only if the data is available..

```
<div ng-if={IsDataAvailable} class="overallsummary_meter_txt left">
Total Price<br>
<span rounded-value items="totalPrice" class="orange_txt"></span>
</div>
```